# Change the value of a column from a list of data according to the column next to it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an import file in Excel format and it contains several data to import on a website. Globally the columns are represented as follows

| Post-title | Post-Category | Post-Image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Line 45 | train | train_1.png |
| Line 59 | train | train_2.png |
| Line 67 | train | train_3.png |
| Line 87 | train | train_1.png |
| Express 45 | bus | bus_1.png |
| AirPort Shuttle | bus | bus_2.png |

As you can see, the last column is the column of the highlighted image. I have a list of images that are related to my categories, here is an example

| Category | Image |
| --- | --- |
| train | train_1.png |
| train | train_2.png |
| train | train_3.png |
| bus | bus_1.png |
| bus | bus_2.png |
| bus | bus_3.png |

Basically, I would like to know if it is possible that when I put the category "Train" there is an image of train among the list that I have (in a random way so as not to always have the same). Because currently I have to process all my rows manually and change the value of the image column manually.

I don't know where to start looking, do you have any leads to help me get started?

Comment: Not completely clear, but as I understand it now you need to adjust the values in the 3rd column based on your 2nd table and randomly pick one of the 'image' values based on the category?

Comment: @JvdV Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do, but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=@SORTBY(FILTER(F$2:F$7,E$2:E$7=B2),RANDARRAY(COUNTIF(E$2:E$7,B2)))
```

Note that `RANDARRAY()` is volatile though.